# How To Retrieve All Properties of An Arbitrary List of Wikidata Items

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have a list of Wikidata items. This list is arbitrary ie the items are *not* connected in any known way. eg. a random list:

```
Q5
Q10
Q11
Q123
```

I'd like to retrieve all properties of these entities, *with one query*. Such that I can see entities, properties and values of those properties all in one table like:

```
itemName.  propertyName.  valueName. 
Q5.        P2.            Q1002.
...
```

How do I do this?

Comment: So, did you read the SPARQL W3C document?

Comment: `select * {values ?s {:Q5 :Q10 :Q11 :Q123 ... } ?s ?p ?o}` - note, this will only return [truthy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements) statements. And indeed, for the statement qualifiers you'd also have to adapt the query.

Comment: The other alternative is to use `DESCRIBE` e.g. `DESCRIBE ?s where { values ?s (:Q5 :Q10 :Q11 :Q123) }` which will also return the triples where these entities are used as objects

Answer (score 0):

There were already good answers in the comments, but I'll add one more. When you want to run the same query for a list of items/inputs, then a `VALUES` clause outside of the `SELECT` is a good option:

```
SELECT * {
  ?itemName ?propertyName ?valueName
}
VALUES ?itemName {
  wd:Q5
  wd:Q10
  wd:Q11
  wd:Q123
}
```